# Use AsyncStorage to store token globally

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I'm learning react-native since one week and i'm confused about something.

Here is the stuff: 
I'm developing an app parsing Imgur API, I somehow managed via a Webview to authenticate myself and get an accessToken, refreshToken etc which I stored locally on my webview component.

Now I want to store this token globally on the app so I did some research and found about AsyncStorage (visibly not secure to store tokens but it's fine it's just an app to practice).

So here is what I understood:

- You give a key and a value  via setItem, they wrap it somehow in a Promise (I need to do some research about this stuff)
- Then you can get it back in another async function.

So here is what I did to set my item in my Login component:

//login.js

```
    import React from 'react'
import {AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, WebView} from 'react-native'
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const webviewRef = 'webview';
const CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxx';

class LoginImgur extends React.Component {
    accessToken : string;
    expiresIn : string;
    refreshToken : string;
    userName : string;

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

async storeItem(key, item) {
    try {
        let jsonOfItem = await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
        return jsonOfItem;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}

_resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Index' })],
});

_changeNavigationState = async (webView) => {
   if (this._splitUrl(webView.url) === true) {
       console.log(this.accessToken);
       let json = this.storeItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', this.accessToken);
       this.props.navigation.dispatch(this._resetAction);
   }
};

_splitUrl(url : String) {
    if (url.search("access_token=") > 0) {
        let array = url.split("=");
            this.accessToken =   array[2].split('&')[0];
            this.expiresIn = array[3].split('&')[0];
            this.refreshToken =  array[5].split('&')[0];
            this.userName =  array[6].split('&')[0];
        return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}



webviewProps = {
    style: styles.webview_container,
    ref: webviewRef,
    javaScriptEnabled: true,
    onNavigationStateChange: this._changeNavigationState.bind(this),
    source: {
        uri: 'https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID + '&response_type=token&state=APPLICATION_STATE',
    }
};

render() {
    return (
        <WebView  {...this.webviewProps}/>
    )

}
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main_container: {
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
    webview_container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});

export default LoginImgur
```

So now I'm in my homescreen and I want to get this accessToken back so I can now make my API calls !!

// Index.js

```
class Index  extends React.Component {
accessToken : string;

async retrieveItem(key) {
    try {
        const retrievedItem =  await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
        const item = JSON.parse(retrievedItem);
        return item;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.retrieveItem('ACCESS_TOKEN').then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.accessToken = value;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Promise is rejected with error: ' + error);
    });
}

_displayAccessToken() {
    console.log(this.accessToken);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            {this._displayAccessToken()}
            <Text>Lol</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

But... It's not working at all. I do get the token in the console.log actually but it doesn't get save in my this.accessToken.

Someone have an idea to pull it of ? Would be a great help... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb6WG.png)

Answer (score 0):

`await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);` is async: it takes a while before the result is available. `render()` runs almost immediately, so at that time `this.accessToken` is not set yet.

One option to display the accesstoken is to store it the component's state. When you call `this.setState({ accessToken: value })`, render() is called again, so then the value will be rendered as soon as the result is available.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.retrieveItem('ACCESS_TOKEN').then((value) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.setState({accessToken: value }); // cause re-rendering
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Promise is rejected with error: ' + error);
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{this.state.accessToken}</Text>
            <Text>Lol</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man that worked :-) !!! But is it not to brutal to put my token in the state ? I mean I don't use it in the render function but just on API related functions. Do you thin of a solution I can work with? Thanks a lot !!